# Camera doesn't work on any video call service

Tags: iphone, video, camera

I found this to be a really weird one. So i dropped my iphone and the camera stopped working. I turned it off and on again and the front camera started working again when on the apple camera however it wont work through video calls - On any app - Facebook, Insta, WhatsApp, Signal. However offline it works fine.

Does anyone know what could be causing this or whether you think it is a hardware or software issue or both?

Comment: Dropping a phone does not change the software, so it must be hardware.

Comment: Yeah but just seems weird it would break it on certain apps, Do you know what part could have broken for this to only be broken when video calling?